# jQuery slick carousel plugin not working

Tags: jquery, plugins, carousel, slick.js

I don't get the slick carousel plugin to work. I already read all the threads here but I'm sure everthing is fine. However it doesn't seems so :D.
Here is my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title>My Now Amazing Webpage</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick-theme.css"/>

  </head>
  <body>

  <div class="test">
          <div><img id="" width="300" height="200" src=""> </div>
          <div><img id="" width="300" height="200" src=""> </div>
          <div><img id="" width="300" height="200" src=""> </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.test').slick({
        setting-name: setting-value
      });
    });
  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I'm sure everything I need is loaded, here is a screen from the chrome dev tool

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aue6k.png)

I also tried to include the css through cdn.jsdelivr.net.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the slick carousel plugin to work you need to set a few **VALID** settings.Yours is not working because of `setting-name: setting-value`.Here's a working example.All the references are added via the CDN so you can just copy and paste it as is in your page and it will work:

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on('ready', function () {
            $(".regular").slick({
                dots: true,
                infinite: true,
                slidesToShow: 3,
                slidesToScroll: 3
            });
        });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="regular slider">
        <div>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=1">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=2">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=3">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=4">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=5">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=6">
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

**Output:**

[image: Slick Carousel]

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It seems like calling slick() does not do anything at all. No error or anything. Everything else seems to be in order, but nothing happens.

Comment: It doesn't work for me too. Looks like now in 2019 it's not supportd with browsers

Comment: Possibly, but luckily we hundreds of other js carousel plug-ins available, right?@yestema

Answer (score 0):

Please end the Slick js file and your plugin trigger code right before ending body tag. Thank you

Comment: Hi @Mohammed, your answer is actually a comment since it does not answer the question. Please consider deleting your answer and adding a comment to the question instead.